# wp_get_attachment_image_src() width and height boolean

Tags: theme-development, images

I have the following code in my theme:

```
<?php
$size = 'large';
$postimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), $size );
$url = $postimage[0];
$h = $postimage[2]
?>

<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $url; ?>); height: <?php echo $h; ?>;"></div>
```

Here's an example `var_dump` output for $postimage:

```
array(3) {
 [0]=> string(99) "{base url here}/uploads/2013/10/h3greendeck.jpg?fit=660%2C660"
 [1]=> bool(false)
 [2]=> bool(false)
}
```

If I remove the `size` argument for `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` to let it use default I get the same result. Why is size returning boolean, when WordPress knows the size of the image? This happens for every single instance of this code, regardless of the post I'm viewing.

Comment: That `fit=` argument is not something I recognize. I have to assume there is a plugin involved, or a theme. Disable your plugins and switch to a bundled theme. Do you still have this problem?

Comment: Seems that some code, probably a plugin, is filtering `wp_get_attachment_image_src` to append that `'fit'` query variable and possibly same code is the culprit of this weird behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a description of the [JetPack's Photon service](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/photon/).

> Photon is an image acceleration and modification service for
>   Jetpack-connected WordPress sites. Converted images are cached
>   automatically and served from the WordPress.com CDN. Images can be
>   cropped, resized, and filtered by using a simple API controlled by GET
>   query arguments. When Photon is enabled in Jetpack, images are updated
>   on the fly.

The Photon API includes the [`fit` GET parameter](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/photon/api/#fit):

```
http://i0.wp.com/example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/abc.jpg?fit=600%2C400
```

where `%2C` is url encoded comma.

It uses the [`image_downsize`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_downsize) filter to overwrite the image retrevial with:

```
// Generate Photon URL
$image = array(
    jetpack_photon_url( $image_url, $photon_args ),
    false,
    false
);
```

where the `width` and `height` are set to `false`.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks! Disabling Photon gave me valid dimensions.